# Access/MySQL - Migration with backward compatibility; Linked tables

Tags: windows-10, mysql, ms-access

**Problem**:

I'm doing this change from a **.NET/MS-Access** system (**that I don't have the code**) to a **PHP/MySQL** (I'm coding) one and I wanted to keep the compatibility with the old system during the trasition.

**Solution attempt**:

I created a **linked table** (ODBC conection) replacing a table in the MS-Access database keeping the same name and structure, but when using the old system to access the table it give me an "Error Establishing a Database Connection".

**Additional data**:

- In access, when I use the option "**convert to local table**" in the context menu of the linked table it starts to work.
- It's not necessary to be a solution using linked tables.
- Using MS-Access 2013, Windows 10, MariaDB 10.4.10

**Related posts**:

- [ACCESS 2003 and MySQL - problems with linked tables](https://superuser.com/questions/1432998/access-2003-and-mysql-problems-with-linked-tables)

Comment: The .net provider  likely was using the oleDB provider for Access. So you would need a oleDB provider for Oracle installed.  If the .net developer used the ODBC providers then this would have a better chance of working. But it is un-likely you get the .net code to just work by hitting a link.

Comment: Your above sample link is a access application - not a .net one - so apples and oranges comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can't do that...

Linked tables are generally only available in Microsoft Access itself. External applications can't use them.

There's no real workaround. The easiest solution I can think of is temporarily supporting Access in your PHP application (which can be really easy or really hard depending on a lot of factors, for example, if you use Laravel there's a package for Access and it can be easy).

Alternatively, you can consider one of the databases read-only and overwrite it with information from the other on a schedule.